# Can kotlin multiplatform app be compatible with Apple CarPlay

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, carplay

I'm developping a messaging app with Kotlin Multiplatform, I would like to know if Apple allows me to be compatible with CarPlay or it needs to be written in Swift mandatory.

Comment: I think it should work totally fine, because there's no separate target - when targeting CarPlay you develop an iOS application, that supports an external display, which in this case is CarPlay. I suggest you to create a new KMM project, make sure it builds for a simulator, add CarPlay target and see if it works

Comment: @PhilDukhov thanks for your comment, I hope too..

Comment: To use CarPlay you need to render using specific CarPlay template UI elements such as https://developer.apple.com/documentation/carplay/cplisttemplate. As long as you can implement code that can conform to the required CarPlay delegate class types and return the required CarPlay template objects then you should be able to do it. You will also need to receive a CarPlay entitlement from Apple before you can start to code.

Comment: After a  quick look at the Kotlin Multiplatform site, I think you will need to develop your CarPlay UI code in Swift, but you can make use of business logic from Kotlin